# How to connect enum/switch with an API value for a specific case swiftUI

Tags: ios, enums, switch-statement, case

I have a currency converter calculator application, Where data is fetched through the API. I am trying to convert inputted data through the enum and switch but unfortunately, I am not sure what is the mistake. Please Can someone help me to understand what shall I do?

You may find my GitHub Link for a project below

https://github.com/Chokaaaa/CurMe

This is my Fetch file

```
import SwiftUI

class FetchData: ObservableObject {

@Published var coversionData: [Currency] = []
@Published var baseCode = "USD"

init() {
    fetch()
}

func fetch() {
    
    let url = "https://open.exchangerate-api.com/v6/latest?base=\(baseCode)"
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, _, _ in
        
        guard let JSONData = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let conversion = try JSONDecoder().decode(Conversion.self, from: JSONData)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.coversionData = conversion.rates.compactMap({ (key,value) -> Currency? in
                    return Currency(currencyName: key, currencyValue: value)
                })
                .filter({ Currency in
                    Currency.currencyName == self.filteredCurrency
                })
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

func updateData(baseCode: String) {
    
    self.baseCode = baseCode
    
    self.coversionData.removeAll()
    fetch()
    
}

}
```

Below you may find an enum where I use a switch with a return of input from the custom number pad (like a calculator) and multiplied on the dummy value. I think I need to fix something in the switch case. Please guys someone help me!! I am struggling.

Bellow, you may find a code for a enum/switch

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurrencyView: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = FetchData()


enum currencyChoice {
    case Kazakhstan, Rubles, Usa
    
    func image() -> Image {
        switch self {
        
        case .Kazakhstan:  return Image("kz")
            
        case .Rubles:      return Image("rub")
            
        case .Usa:         return Image("usa")
            
        }
    }
    
    func operation(_ input: Double) -> Double {
        switch self {
        case .Kazakhstan: return (input * 2)
        case .Rubles: return (input * 3)
        case .Usa: return (input * 5)
        
        }
    }
    
}

var function : currencyChoice
@Binding var state : CalculationState

var body: some View {
    
    
    
    return function.image()
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .onTapGesture {
            state.currentNumber = function.operation(state.currentNumber)
        }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, enum is not suggested with **store property** so better to avoid it or use the **static property** of enum.

Definitely it'll fix your issue.